# Что за запрос типа ws://laravel/белиберда приложение на vue отравляет на сервер?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket

Делаю приложение на vue с бэкэндом на laravel. Приложение на vue отправляет периодически запрос на сервер типа ws://laravel/белиберда Для чего это делается? Сервер на ларавеле отвечает с кодом либо 101 либо 200. Так все работает. Но для чего эти запросы? Я сам ничего такого в приложении не программировал. Ws - это веб-сокет как я понимаю

Answer (score 2):

ws - это websocket - это такая возможность сделать tcp (постоянное) подключение, но для javascript в браузере. Зачем это нужно? просто обычный http работает по принципу запрос-ответ. При этом запрос можно отправить только от клиента. А если сервер хочет что то послать, то он не может этого сделать. Поэтому придумали всякие Polling. То есть, клиент подключается к серверу, а сервер не отвечает сразу. Но когда появляются данные - шлет.

Веб сокеты это решают, делая все прозрачно. В результате, сервер может прислать сообщение браузеру. Например, "данные в таблице обновились" или "вот новое сообщение в чатике". А в браузере просто сработает колбек.

Конечно, можно все сделать и на polling, и на постоянном дерганье сервера, но установка соединения не дешевая операция. А постоянное соединение часто заметно лучше. Сильно лучше.

Если почитать [введение в laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting#introduction), там прямо об этом и написано.